# How to display row number(only visible row) in a column of gridview after hiding certain row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is my front-end code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NO.">
                                      <ItemTemplate ><div ID="PicCounter" style="text-align: center; color:black"><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %></div></ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
```

While, this is my back-end code:

```
 int sum = 0;
    protected void gv_Action_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                Label Action = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("ACTION");//take lable id

                if (Action.Text.ToString() == "0")
                {
                    e.Row.Visible = false;
                }
                else if (Action.Text.ToString() != "")
                {
                    sum += int.Parse(Action.Text);
                    lblTotalNoti.Text = sum.ToString();


                }



            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Write("gv_Action_RowDataBound() Error: " + ex.Message.ToString() + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            ERRORMSG.Text = "gv_Action_RowDataBound() Error: " + ex.Message.ToString();

        }

    }
```

I want to put row numbering for each visible row in a column of grid view after hiding some row.My problem is the row that i was hiding also got numbered.Please help me, I'm beginner.

Comment: Why don't you hide those row in DataTable or dataset itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself:Add this to the back-end

```
if (e.Row.Visible == true)
                {
                    numVisible += 1;

                    Label lblRowCounter = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblRowCounter");//take lable id

                    lblRowCounter.Text = numVisible.ToString();

                }
```